# OpenVPN connect by .openvpn file. How to import settings?

Tags: openvpn

OS: Last Elementary with Phantenom
I get ovpn file. Now i want import it by 1-2 clicks but how it possible?
Network Settings\VPN+\
1. Import a saved VPN configuration - didnt help it says:

> The file 'Germany_freeopenvpn_tcp.ovpn' could not be read or does not
>   contain recognized VPN connection information
>
> Error: the plugin does not support import capability.

BTW: network-manager-openvpn is already the newest version (1.1.93-1ubuntu1.1). 
(installed as i understend.)

2. Choose OpenVPN, here i can manual enter all settings from OVPN file. But its too long and i can make a mistake.

So question is: what i need to install to import OVPN settings by 1-2 clicks.

Rethorical question why its not work from box???